# Collapse elements of array of structs in BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, json, struct, google-bigquery

I have an array of structs in BigQuery that looks like:

```json
"categories": [
    {
        "value": "A",
        "question": "Q1",
    },
    {
        "value": "B",
        "question": "Q2",
    },
    {
        "value": "C",
        "question": "Q3",
    }
]
```

I'd like to collapse the values "A", "B" and "C" into a separate column, and the value for this particular row should be something like "A - B - C".

How can I do this with a query in BigQuery?

Comment: what you mean by *something like "A - B - C"*? can you show expected resulted row?

Comment: A new char column with its value being 'A - B - C'. The separator is not important, something like 'A B C' or "ABC" works for me as well

Comment: Do you want to preserve the array rows and only add a new column within the array? Or do you want to preserve the array and aggregate it into a new table column? I think it would be good to see some example output with at least 2 table rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select id, 
  ( select string_agg(value, ' - ') 
    from t.questions_struct) values
from questions t
```

if applied to sample data in your question/answer -

```
with questions as (
  SELECT 1 AS id,
    [
        STRUCT("A" as value, "Q1" as question),
        STRUCT("B" as value, "Q2" as question),
        STRUCT("C" as value, "Q3" as question)
    ] AS questions_struct
)
```

- output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an array of structs, you can use:

```
select (select q.value from unnest(ar) q where q.question = 'q1') as q1,
       (select q.value from unnest(ar) q where q.question = 'q2') as q2,
       (select q.value from unnest(ar) q where q.question = 'q3') as q3
from t;
```

Comment: And is there a way to "scale" it to an arbitrary number of questions? Some rows might have 1, some may have 2, and some may have 50.

Comment: @DavidMasip . . . I don't think there is a way to put the values in separate columns.  You could combine them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done with the following code:

```sql
with questions as (
  SELECT 1 AS id,
    [
        STRUCT("A" as value, "Q1" as question),
        STRUCT("B" as value, "Q2" as question),
        STRUCT("C" as value, "Q3" as question)
    ] AS questions_struct
), unnested as (
    select * from questions, unnest(questions_struct) as questions_struct 
) select id, string_agg(value, ' - ') from unnested group by 1
```

Comment: . . My answer is much better precisely because it avoids the outer aggregation.

Comment: Does it perform faster?

Comment: . . Of course, that depends on the data.  But on larger data sets, avoiding the `group by` can be a significant win in performance.  It avoids a lot of data movement.